# Separar todos os itens de uma string

Tags: visual-basic-6, vbscript

Eu to tentando fazer um sistema de `save/load`, estou travado na parte de carregar as cartas do jogo, que são numeradas por exemplo: **1**,**2**,**3**.

A `string` contém os números das cartas entre outras informações:

```
Nome|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9|59000|50%

nome   cartas          money   reputação
```

Meu código de `load`:

```
Dim Nome As String = values(0)
Dim Cartas As String = values(1)
Dim Dinheiro As String = values(2)
Dim Reputacao As String = values(3)
MsgBox(Nome)
MsgBox(Cartas)
MsgBox(Dinheiro)
MsgBox(Reputacao)
Dim cards() As String = Cartas.Split(","c)
'MsgBox(cards)
Dim word As String
Dim b As Integer
For Each word In cards
    b = b +1
    MsgBox(word)
Next
Dim nCartas = b
```

Eu tenho o número de cartas, como faço pra pegar `X` quantidade de itens da `string Cards`?, por exemplo: o `nCartas` é `10`, eu quero pegar as 10 `strings` da Cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim bar() As String
Dim foo() As String
Dim i As Byte

bar = Split("Nome|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9|59000|50%", "|")

foo = Split(bar(1), ",")

For i = LBound(foo) To UBound(foo)
    Debug.Print foo(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Oi, obrigado por responder!

o Visual Studio ta me retornando esse erro:
https://image.ibb.co/bM1s5b/232323.png

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigado!