# Sem idéias para lógica de Load

Tags: vb.net

Pedi ajuda recentemente neste tópico> [Separar todos os itens de uma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241889/separar-todos-os-itens-de-uma-string)

O problema é que, o meu jogo é um Card-Game offline que tem um "inventário" de cartas, só que eu não faço a minima ideia de como eu faço pra de fato "colocar as cartas no inventário".
Eu pensei inicialmente em guardar as cartas através de números, como eu mostro no tópico acima.

Só que como eu "guardo" as cartas in-game pra eu usar?

Eu tenho uma form aonde eu chamo de "Meu Time" que ficam os 5 slots das cartas e eu seleciono (em cada slot) uma carta através de uma combo-box, são divididas em:

Top
JG
Mid
Adc
Sup

Cada um é uma combobox.

Até agora eu tenho um código que carrega um save que divide as cartas através de números, agora, como eu faço pra transformar os números em dados para as combobox?

O código de load é esse:

```
  Dim bar() As String
    Dim foo() As String
    Dim i As Byte

    bar = Split("Nome|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9|59000|50%", "|")

    foo = Split(bar(1), ",")

    For i = LBound(foo) To UBound(foo)
      Dim cartaAtual as string = foo(i)
    Next i
```

Como eu faço pra dividir número por número e colocar eles na Combobox?
Preciso de ajuda pra achar uma lógica.

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver isso ???

Comment: Resolvi sim, eu utilizei
if save.contains pra determinar se o save continha tal ID da carta, se tivesse, eu adicionava na combobox, obrigado!

Comment: @LuanDevecchi por que não responde aqui o que te resolveu?